# Rails and partials, is there a more efficent way of writing this...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, partial

I've got a partial in a loop like so...

```
<% things.each do |thing| %><%= render :partial => "thingy", :locals => { :something  => something, :thing  => thing } %><% end %>
```

This just doesn't seem very railsy, I was wondering if there more efficient way of putting partials in a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename your partial from 'thingy' to 'thing' and do this:

```
<%= render things, :locals => { :something => :goatse } %>
```

I couldn't think of anything more Railsy.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<%= render :partial => "thingy", :collection =>things, :locals => { :something  => something} %>
```